# Showing Coreplot barchart value without selection

Tags: ios, core-plot, bar-chart

Currently i am refering to following coreplot [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2) to learn bar chart plotting.

So while showing the value w.r.t each bar user has to tap each bar & finally `CPTBarPlotDelegate` method gets called & value is shown

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

}
```

But what i am looking is without selecting any bar, it should show me all the values in 90 degree orientation.

Is this possible. How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use data labels with any plot to label each value. Set the `labelTextStyle` to turn on basic numeric labels. Use the following properties to customize the labels:

- `labelOffset`
- `labelRotation`
- `labelField`
- `labelTextStyle`
- `labelFormatter`
- `labelShadow`

Use one of the following datasource methods to provide custom labels if the basic text labels aren't enough or if you want to skip some labels:

```
-(NSArray *)dataLabelsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```